# Can we create dummy data in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have only one table in the Crystal Report(11) and I am working on the time field which is string they do the entry in every 15 minute in that field.
example: 7:15, 7:30, 7:45, 8:15, and 8:30

I have to find out the missing record (if any) of every 15 minutes, like in the above example 8:00 is missing, so I have to show in the report that 8:00 time is missing.

I tried with `timevalue(15)`, then adding to the field and then comparing it with the next value if it is then suppress the detail section, but formula is not working. Maybe there is some mistake in my formula. Can somebody help me?

Comment: 1. What interface is used for the data entry? 2. Do you save the entry values somewhere (database, dataset etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend modifying your data before it gets to Crystal:

1. Add a 1 column table.  This table will list every 'timeslot' of interest and should never need to be updated (4 timeslots an hour * 24 hours = 96 records?).
2. Left join from your index table to your original source table.  This join will be more complicated if your data is grouped in some way, but is still possible.

Thus, you will have at least 1 record for each timeslot.  If there are no records for that timeslot, then very value except the timeslot will be null.

Comment: It's third party database, I can not add any table in it. If I can do anything crystal report side that will be good. Thanks for responding.

Comment: In that case, you can still try doing all this in the SQL layer of your data connection.  I can't give any more help on that though since I never did that with Crystal. Good luck.